# Terraform nested loop expression

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I'm trying to construct a collection to loop over based on nested data. The example below shows the code I am trying to use:

repos.tfvars

```
repositories = {
  workflows = {
    description                     = "Reusable workflow repository"
    topics                          = ["github-actions", "reusable-workflows"]
  },
  aws-network-speciality = {
    description          = "AWS Network Speciality study repository"
    topics               = ["amazon-web-services", "aws", "terraform", "iac"]
  }
}
```

main.tf

```
locals {
  terraform_repos  = { for each, repo in var.repositories : each => repo if contains(["terraform"], repo)}

resource "github_repository_file" "tflint" {
  for_each       = local.terraform_repos
  repository     = each.key
  file           = ".tflint"
  content        = file("${path.module}/github_repository_files/.tflint")
  commit_message = "chore(managed-by-terraform): tflint configuration file"
}
```

The desired outcome is that tflint is uploaded to each repository with the terraform topic.

Currently `local.terraform_repos` returns an empty map - I'm just unsure how to drill down into `var.repositories` to query the `topics[]` and then return the name of the repo(s) for the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contains` should be used for `topics` and also you have wrong arguments. It should be:

```
  terraform_repos  = { for each, repo in var.repositories : each => repo if contains(repo.topics, "terraform")}
```

Comment: It did yes. Thank you. Replied previously but didn’t submit.